# TensorFlow fit() and GradientTape - number of epochs are different

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

if I define the architecture of a neural network using only dense fully connected layers and train them such that there are two models which are trained using **model.fit()** and **GradientTape**. Both the methods of training use the *same* model architecture.

The randomly initialized weights are shared between the two models and all other parameters such as optimizer, loss function and metrics are also the same.

Dimensions of training and testing sets are:
X_train = (960, 4), y_train = (960,), X_test = (412, 4) & y_test = (412,)

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler, RobustScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow_model_optimization as tfmot
from tensorflow_model_optimization.sparsity import keras as sparsity


def create_nn():
    """
    Function to create a
    Neural Network
    """
    model = Sequential()                                                    

    model.add(
        Dense(
            units = 4, activation = 'relu',
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal(),
            input_shape = (4,)
        )
    )

    model.add(
        Dense(
            units = 3, activation = 'relu',
            kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.GlorotNormal()
        )
    )

    model.add(
        Dense(
            units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'
        )
    )

    """
    # Compile the defined NN model above-
    model.compile(
        loss = 'binary_crossentropy',  # loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001),
        metrics=['accuracy']
    )
    """

    return model


# Instantiate a model- model = create_nn()

# Save weights for fair comparison- model.save_weights("Random_Weights.h5", overwrite=True)


# Create datasets to be used for GradientTape-
# Use tf.data to batch and shuffle the dataset train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (X_train, y_train)).shuffle(100).batch(32)

test_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    (X_test, y_test)).shuffle(100).batch(32)

# Define early stopping- callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', patience=3,
    min_delta = 0.001, mode = 'min' )

# Train defined model- history_orig = model.fit(
    x = X_train, y = y_train,
    batch_size = 32, epochs = 500,
    validation_data = (X_test, y_test),
    callbacks = [callback],
    verbose = 1 )


# Instantiate a model- model_gt = create_nn()

# Restore random weights as used by the previous model for fair comparison- model_gt.load_weights("Random_Weights.h5")


# Choose an optimizer and loss function for training- loss_fn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy() optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001)

# Select metrics to measure the error & accuracy of model.
# These metrics accumulate the values over epochs and then
# print the overall result- train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name = 'train_loss') train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name = 'train_accuracy')

test_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name = 'test_loss') test_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name = 'train_accuracy')


# Use tf.GradientTape to train the model-

@tf.function def train_step(data, labels):
    """
    Function to perform one step of Gradient
    Descent optimization
    """

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model_gt(data)
        loss = loss_fn(labels, predictions)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model_gt.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model_gt.trainable_variables))

    train_loss(loss)
    train_accuracy(labels, predictions)


@tf.function def test_step(data, labels):
    """
    Function to test model performance
    on testing dataset
    """

    predictions = model_gt(data)
    t_loss = loss_fn(labels, predictions)

    test_loss(t_loss)
    test_accuracy(labels, predictions)


EPOCHS = 100

# User input- minimum_delta = 0.001 patience = 3

patience_val = np.zeros(patience)


# Dictionary to hold scalar metrics- history = {}

history['accuracy'] = np.zeros(EPOCHS) history['val_accuracy'] = np.zeros(EPOCHS) history['loss'] = np.zeros(EPOCHS) history['val_loss'] = np.zeros(EPOCHS)

for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    # Reset the metrics at the start of the next epoch
    train_loss.reset_states()
    train_accuracy.reset_states()
    test_loss.reset_states()
    test_accuracy.reset_states()

    for x, y in train_ds:
        train_step(x, y)

    for x_t, y_t in test_ds:
        test_step(x_t, y_t)

    template = 'Epoch {0}, Loss: {1:.4f}, Accuracy: {2:.4f}, Test Loss: {3:.4f}, Test Accuracy: {4:4f}'

    history['accuracy'][epoch] = train_accuracy.result()
    history['loss'][epoch] = train_loss.result()
    history['val_loss'][epoch] = test_loss.result()
    history['val_accuracy'][epoch] = test_accuracy.result()

    print(template.format(epoch + 1, 
                          train_loss.result(), train_accuracy.result()*100,
                          test_loss.result(), test_accuracy.result()*100))

    if epoch > 2:
        # Computes absolute differences between 3 consecutive loss values-
        differences = np.abs(np.diff(history['val_loss'][epoch - 3:epoch], n = 1))

        # Checks whether the absolute differences is greater than 'minimum_delta'-
        check =  differences > minimum_delta

        # print('differences: {0}'.format(differences))

        # Count unique element with it's counts-
        # elem, count = np.unique(check, return_counts=True)
        # print('\nelem = {0}, count = {1}'.format(elem, count))

        if np.all(check == False):
        # if elem.all() == False and count == 2:
            print("\n\nEarlyStopping Evoked! Stopping training\n\n")
            break
```

In "model.fit()" method, it takes around 82 epochs, while GradientTape method takes 52 epochs.

Why is there this discrepancy in the number of epochs?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please, fix the indentation of your code, provide the required imports to execute the code and make sure the code is minimal. In any case, this question is better suited for Stack Overflow or Data Science SE.

Comment: @nbro fixed indentations and added imports